# MySQL Multiple SELECT Not Working

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select an overall sum of totals from different tables into one query. For some reason this query below used to work but now returns NULL. If I execute the single queries they do return a sum but not adding them together. Any one perhaps can see what I'm doing wrong?

```
SELECT
(
        (SELECT SUM(a.Total) FROM table1 a) + 
        (SELECT SUM(c.Total) FROM table2 c) + 
        (SELECT SUM(eb.Total) FROM table3 eb) + 
        (SELECT SUM(h.Amount) FROM table4 h) + 
        (SELECT SUM(n.Total) FROM table5 n) + 
        (SELECT SUM(mbo.Total) FROM table6 mbo)
   )
AS Overral_Amount_Total
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(sub.col) AS Overral_Amount_Total
FROM
(
  SELECT SUM(Total) AS col FROM table1 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUM(Total) FROM table2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUM(Total) FROM table3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM table4
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUM(Total) FROM table5
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUM(Total) FROM table6
) AS sub;
```

The point is (one of your tables is empty/contains all `NULL` in specific column):

```
CREATE TABLE tab(col INT);

SELECT SUM(col)
FROM tab;
-- will return NULL
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/106e5/1/0)**</kbd>

For empty table it will return `NULL` and anything added to `NULL` is `NULL`.

Comment: Yes you're right @lad2025, I figured that one of the tables was returning NULL because it's empty... So your comment above is true...Thanks for the answer as your way works.!

Answer (score 1):

You have scalar subqueries that always return one row.  That means that you can also use `COALESCE()` within the subquery:

```
SELECT (
        (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(a.Total), 0) FROM table1 a) + 
        (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(c.Total), 0) FROM table2 c) + 
        (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(eb.Total), 0) FROM table3 eb) + 
        (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(h.Amount), 0) FROM table4 h) + 
        (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(n.Total), 0) FROM table5 n) + 
        (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(mbo.Total), 0) FROM table6 mbo)
       ) AS Overall_Amount_Total
```

This can be quite handy if your actually query used correlated subqueries.  This solution would be much simpler to implement than the `UNION ALL` solution.